# PostGIS calculate distances from one point to multiple points

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

In PostgreSQL 12.1 64bit and PostGIS 3.0, I have two small tables of points. I want to determine the distance from one point in one table to multiple points in the other table. The tables both have the same SRID: 26910.

The WKT for the table with multiple points,`ebd_sampl`, has these coordinates:

```
ID           geom
'S6485705'  'POINT(473697.203011859 5107286.1114417)'
'S16187642' 'POINT(473388.313557094 5107381.77541894)'
'S21737009' 'POINT(473304.975396136 5107449.75936742)'
'S27967642' 'POINT(472992.535028299 5107506.05876625)'
'S30893534' 'POINT(472638.34972214 5107604.73782347)'
'S35264483  'POINT(473106.919925334 5107464.0012127)'
```

The WKT point from the other table,`grid_sampl`, is:
`'POINT(473144.563851624 5107073.33440939)'`

I can write an inner query with a WHERE clause to select one point in the first inner query and get one distance, between one point in each table. I thought by taking out the WHERE clause in the first inner query, that query would be more general and return a table with distances for all points in first table to the selected point in the second table. But I don't know how to write the SQL for that.

I tried:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
    (SELECT geom FROM p_loc.ebd_sampl),
    (SELECT geom FROM p_loc.grid_sampl WHERE data = '441062')
);
```

And this is the result:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I'd like a table like (the distance values are made up here):

```
ID          distance
'S6485705'  400
'S16187642' 550
'S21737009' 633
'S27967642' 401
'S30893534' 700
'S35264483' 501
```

What SQL should I use so that the respective distances for each point in the first table to the one selected point in the second table are returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing both tables in the `FROM` clause and filtering the values you want in the `WHERE` clause, e.g.

```
SELECT id,ST_Distance(t.geom,grid_sampl.geom) 
FROM t,grid_sampl
WHERE grid_sampl.data = '441062' ;
```

Example

```
CREATE TABLE t (id TEXT, geom GEOMETRY);
INSERT INTO t VALUES
('S6485705',  'SRID=26910;POINT(473697.203011859 5107286.1114417)'),
('S16187642', 'SRID=26910;POINT(473388.313557094 5107381.77541894)'),
('S21737009', 'SRID=26910;POINT(473304.975396136 5107449.75936742)'),
('S27967642', 'SRID=26910;POINT(472992.535028299 5107506.05876625)'),
('S30893534', 'SRID=26910;POINT(472638.34972214 5107604.73782347)'),
('S35264483', 'SRID=26910;POINT(473106.919925334 5107464.0012127)');

CREATE TABLE grid_sampl (data TEXT, geom GEOMETRY);
INSERT INTO grid_sampl VALUES ('441062','SRID=26910;POINT(473144.563851624 5107073.33440939)');

SELECT id,ST_Distance(t.geom,grid_sampl.geom) 
FROM t,grid_sampl
WHERE grid_sampl.data = '441062' ;

    id     |   st_distance    
-----------+------------------
 S6485705  | 592.185871921898
 S16187642 | 393.128191928728
 S21737009 | 409.179193802818
 S27967642 | 458.653608010902
 S30893534 | 733.922566341344
 S35264483 | 392.476262206356
(6 Zeilen)
```

Comment: I'm still learning to use SQL. Your answer makes perfect sense and I should have thought of that first. The query I used came from a source that answered a similar question to one I was working on and I thought I just needed the modification I presented in my question above. Thanks for the help.